# How to push key and value in array through php?

Tags: php

i have one sql query like this

```
SELECT wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id=wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item' AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key='_qty' AND wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id=1477
```

Now this query gives me two results like this

```
order_item_name                     meta_value
Handicap Accessible Porta Potty         1
Sani Stand Handwashing Station          1
```

and i want to push this into array with key.

i tried this code for push

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($item_name)) {
    $order_items['name'] = $row2['order_item_name'];
    $order_items['quantity'] = $row2['meta_value'];
}
```

but above code push only one element.
Please help

Comment: You're not pushing anything there, you're assigning. Try actually writing some code with `array_push` (or, more simply, `[]`) and see if by some miracle writing the right code makes it work :p

Comment: you have to use multidimensional array for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

Make each element of your array into another array like this:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($item_name)) {
    $order_items[] = array('name' => $row2['order_item_name'],'quantity' => $row2['meta_value']);
}
```

Or simply make it a two dimensional array pushing each value into a numeric field:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($item_name)) {
    $order_items['name'][] = $row2['order_item_name'];
    $order_items['quantity'][] = $row2['meta_value'];
}
```

The first method will result in the following structure:

```
array(
[0] = array(
    name => name1,
    quantity => qty1),
[1] = array(
    name => name2,
    quantity => qty2)
)
```

While the second method will give you something like this:

```
array(
[name] = array(
    [0] => name1,
    [1] => name2
    ),
[quantity] = array(
    [0] => qty1,
    [1] => qty2
    )
);
```

It really depends on what you want to do with it later and how.

Answer (score 1):

First, write the query like this so that the field mapping is already done in the SQL result set:

```
SELECT wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name name, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value quantity
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items 
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id=wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id 
WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item' AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key='_qty' AND wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id=1477
```

Then, build the array:

```
$values = [];
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_name)) !== false) {
    $values[] = $row;
}
```

If you want to build a key-value array (in which case the field mapping is less important):

```
$values = [];
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_name)) !== false) {
    $values[$row['name']] = $row['quantity'];
}
```